# Add iOS pods and Android dependencies in Ionic/Cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I need to add an image resizer library in my ionic project (pod and dependency for iOS/Android respectively). How should I integrate this?

First, create a Cordova plugin and then add the plugin to my project?

Is there any examples I can follow to achieve this.

Comment: Why not just use an existing plugin?

Comment: there isn't an exisitng plugin for it

Comment: https://github.com/JoschkaSchulz/cordova-plugin-image-resizer

Comment: I need more functionalities. Hence looking at importing other libraries which provide them.